# integrate java doc in own javadoc

Tags: documentation, javadoc, java

Is it possible to integrate JDK own documentation in my project documentation?

So I basically want, in example, the `java.lang.String` javadoc linked to my own documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @see and {@link} annotation to refer to the javadoc classes.

```
/** 
 * {@link java.lang.String}
 * @see java.lang.String
 */
```

If you want a link to the online javadoc, use this:

```
/**    
 * @see <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html">java.lang.String</a>
 */
```

Comment: thank you Giovanni. I tried, but I still not have a html link to the String javadoc.

Comment: sorry I didnt understand your request, you can check my edited response ;)